# I wanted the object to follow the character model

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

hey all I was trying to add a needle on the character's hand so it can follow where he is going , I tried many methods like add an empty and keep transform but its not following the hand it keeps still stand, the character is walking forward I just wanted the syrinnge to seem like he is holding it and walking , its kind of hard process I dont know why I have A hard time figuring it out , I can upload a gifs but I dont know how to actually do it so this an  image , or I can upload my blend if you ask for more details , thanks all [image]

Comment: give it a Child Of constraint with the hand bone as target?

Comment: so basically I tried it, but the problem is i put the armature as a target but still not following , or should i try the bone hand itself? I reckon  i need to go to pose mode and find the hand bone ? still confused sorry I probably what exactly to do

Comment: yes the target needs to be the hand bone

Comment: my life saver , you are the best moonboots , always here helpful and give best tips , best regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a *Child Of* constraint to your needle object, with the hand bone as *Target*:

[image]

If the character needs to drop the needle, I recommend the [Dynamic Parent](https://github.com/romanvolodin/dynamic_parent) addon, by Roman Volodin, it makes things easier.